# Does ばかり (meaning 'just happened') have to be a voluntary action (like たところ?)

Tags: words, past, particle-ばかり

Is ばかり the same as たところ in the sense that the action must be voluntary? e.g. Winter just ended, could you use ばかり？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Both*** 「ばかり」 and 「ところ」 can be used to describe the endings of either voluntary or involuntary actions.

It is perfectly grammatical and natural-sounding to say all of the following:

・「やっと冬{ふゆ}が終{お}わった（ばかり/ところ）です。まだ海水浴{かいすいよく}には行{い}けません。」 "Winter has just ended at long last.  We couldn't go bathing in the sea yet."

・「今{いま}、晩{ばん}ご飯{はん}を食{た}べた（ばかり/ところ）です。おなかが一杯{いっぱい}です。」 "I've just finished eating dinner. I am stuffed."